# Simple proxy to cache HTTP responses

Tags: c#, tcp, proxy

First of all, I'm a noob at networking and and not familiar with much networking terminology so pardon my ignorance.

I'm trying to write a proxy that will intercept requests made by an automated browser (Selenium) and record the responses. The proxy will run on the same machine as the browser. Later on, when the same request is made, it'll respond with a cached response, instead of contacting the server again, such that I can replay the whole automation while disconnected from the internet. I'd like this to work regardless of the website.

I've tried [this proxy](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/93301/Implementing-a-Multithreaded-HTTP-HTTPS-Debugging) and it works fine non secure sites but on HTTPS sites I get the error: `An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine.` Just found out this is due to the proxy throwing an `The server mode SSL must use a certificate with the associated private key` error when trying to authenticate.

I see that the proxy has a certificate for secure connections. I'm not sure if I even need that since I don't need to look into the request/response. The way I see it is: The browser wants to send bytes to a server so it asks the OS to send them. The OS sends me the bytes instead, and I send them to the server. The bytes that come out of my machine are exactly the same as if there was no proxy. Then the server responds and my proxy intercepts the bytes and send them back to the browser, and again, the bytes are exactly the same as if there was no proxy. Also, if a request has been made to X (assuming I can at least see the (maybe encripted) URL) with Y content (maybe also encripted) and another X, Y request has been made previously, then respond with the cached response.

Comment: https is not THAT simple as you described :) So after all - is that required to proxy https sites also or not?

Comment: @Evk Yes, it should handle https sites as well, But I'm confused as to why is not the whole thing reducible to bytes coming in and out of my machine and the possibility of someone on the middle looking at them.

Comment: There are several reasons, but most obvious for your case is that you won't see url. You will only know DNS of server request is being made to and everything else is encrypted. Same story with server response - everything is encrypted. So you actually have no idea what is being requested. If that is not enough - add to this that encryption key is generated at random when https connection is established which means you cannot cache encrypted response anyway, because it might be invalid for all subsequent requests.

Comment: That means to do what you want you have to perform so called "man in the middle" attack (you can read more on this because it won't fit into comment), for which your proxy will need to generate certificates and you will have to trust certificates issued by that proxy to avoid ton of browser warnings.

Comment: @Evk I finally got it (kind of) working with a test cert, but had to set browser to ignore ssl errors. But I'm still curios about how would I go about proxying the data without a cert and without decrypting it, just sending it back and forth as is, even if I can't see any of the data the URL as you mentioned.

Comment: There is a HTTP method called CONNECT which is designed for that. Browser will make a request to your proxy like "CONNECT google.com on port 443". You establish a connection to google.com on 443 and then just forward tcp traffict to\from server and client - just as you described. You cannot deciper it so you cannot cache it, but you can just forward it.

Comment: So if you have working code which can intercept ssl with fake certificate - just remove everything related to decryption\encryption there, because that code most likely already handles CONNECT.